# QQuickImageProvider PyQt5

Tags: python, qml, pyqt5

I try to use **QQuickImageProvider** send QImage to QML, everything work well in c++ Qt5.9.2,but I try similar code with PyQt5(5.9.2), QML just says error:**ImageProvider supports Image type but has not implemented requestImage()**,but in fact,I implemented the **requestImage()**,here my code:

**main.py:**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtQml import *
from PyQt5.QtQuick import *

class MyImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyImageProvider, self).__init__(QQuickImageProvider.Image) 

    def requestImage(self, p_str, size):
        img = QImage(300, 300, QImage.Format_RGBA8888)
        img.fill(Qt.red)
        return img, img.size()

app = QGuiApplication([])    

viewer = QQuickView()
viewer.engine().addImageProvider("myprovider", MyImageProvider())
viewer.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
viewer.setSource(QUrl("example.qml"))
viewer.show()

app.exec()
```

**example.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {
    id: root
    width: 800
    height: 600
    Image{
         // width: 300
         // height: 300
         source: "image://myprovider/test.png"
    }
}
```

Perhaps **requestImage()** has different parameters and return values in python and c++,I'm sure that's right in format. refer to some examples, http://nullege.com/codes/search/PyQt5.QtQuick.QQuickImageProvider, I don't know what's wrong with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I'm reviewing the problem is QQuickView or QQmlEngine, these classes are obsolete.

I recommend you use QQmlApplicationEngine:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtQml import *
from PyQt5.QtQuick import *


class MyImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyImageProvider, self).__init__(QQuickImageProvider.Image)

    def requestImage(self, p_str, size):
        img = QImage(300, 300, QImage.Format_RGBA8888)
        img.fill(Qt.red)
        return img, img.size()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.addImageProvider("myprovider", MyImageProvider())
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile("example.qml"))
    if len(engine.rootObjects()) == -1:
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**example.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Image{
         anchors.fill : parent
         source: "image://myprovider/test.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. It seems it was because the provider instance got lost after passed onto addImageProvider(). I resolved this issue like following.

```
app = QGuiApplication([])    

viewer = QQuickView()
provider = MyImageProvider() # keep this instance during your app running
viewer.engine().addImageProvider("myprovider", provider)
viewer.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
viewer.setSource(QUrl("example.qml"))
viewer.show()

app.exec()
```